# couldn't install pandas library in visual code studio for linux environiment

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio, ubuntu-18.04

I have been working on python for a quite some time now but I am new to visual code studio and Linux. The OS I'm using is Ubuntu 18.04.3 . I installed python extension in visual code studio. But it did not has pandas library installed. Also we cannot install packages from python terminal. So I installed pandas from Linux terminal using `pip install pandas`. I reopened my VS code and I still couldn't import pandas library. It is still throwing `module not found` error. Can someone please explain how to install pandas in VS code for linux?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas you installed with pip must be installed with the python you have in your system (if you are not using virtual env).

In VS code set the python interpreter to be used as same present in your linux terminal.

Have a look at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial . It is explained in detail over here.

But we should try to use virtual env so that these type of problems can be resolved quickly.